# Windows WLS, Postgresql on Windows and Rails, cannot build a db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to work with Windows WLS.
I have installed ruby and rails and they work (apart the annoying warning).
I've installed postgresql client on Ubuntu/WLS, and postgresql server on windows.
When i try to connect via:

```
psql -p 5432 -h localhost -U postgres
```

all run correctly.
When i try to launch:

```
rails db:create
```

i have this error:

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error can means that the Postgresql server is not running. Try starting it

---

```
sudo systemctl start postgresql
```

---

and Make sure that the server starts on boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

or 
This issue can comes from installing the postgres package without a version number.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge postgresql
```

and reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-(what is the current version)
```

Comment: I'm using postgresql on Windows so no server to start on ubuntu/wls, only client. I've purged and reinstalled the clients with the correct version but it don't run the same.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. If someone needs, in the configuration file we need to add host: localhost